# Write multiple lines to file descriptor without here-doc and delete it after reading <&{fd} without blocking

Tags: bash, file-descriptors

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

auth() { 
    exec 3<<AUTH
$1
$2
AUTH
}

auth test pwd
sh -c 'cat <&3'
```

I want to temporarily store credentials in an auth file/mem of the format `user/npass`, which has to get deleted once it is read by `<&3`. The binary, that reads it runs infinitely in a docker alpine container with bash5+ and is executed in a `/bin/sh` environment, so sub-shells like `cat <(echo -e "$1\n$2")` won't work and deleting the temp file after the command ends is no option.

The code above works, but i don't like the look of the here-document without indentations. I know i can use real tabs with `<<-EOF` but this will end up in a public repository and has to function even when some editors replace tabs with 4 spaces, so i can't rely on that.

Isn't there an alternative that works like `echo $user>$3` or putting the output from `(echo -e "$1\n$2")` into the fd?

Whatever i tried, i either end up with the input `<&3` blocking and waiting for EOF or the fd content not getting erased.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstracting from whether it's a good practice, what you're trying to do, here's one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

auth() { 
    exec 3< <(printf "%s\n%s\n" "$1" "$2")
}

auth test pwd
sh -c 'cat <&3'
```

Result, as expected:

```
$ ./auth.bash 
test
pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you could always do:

```
auth() {
  exec 3<<< "$1"$'\n'"$2"
}
```

Or:

```
auth() {
  eval $'exec 3<< EOF\n$1\n$2\nEOF'
}
```

Not sure that'd help much wrt legibility.

Bash versions prior to 5.1 used a deleted temporary file for here documents or here strings and since 5.1 use a pipe for short contents and a deleted temporary file for the ones that don't fit in a pipe.

That means that with newer versions, the data can only be read once from that fd 3 (no rewind (`lseek()`) possible, and one can't read from the beginning again by opening `/proc/self/fd/3`)